# A word for a bad company/firm/work of employment

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a single word or two words that would describe a bad company/firm or place of work. It could be bad working environment and/or place that produces bad results.

If possible the word should be non-archaic and not belong to a very concrete type of company (like horse-stall-keepers or radio-controlling that would not have place in the modern world as much ). It would be great if the word would be understandable by today's native English speaker (American or British) without looking into a dictionary ( something that was in common use no longer than 100 years ago hopefully! ).

Examples of use:

> Why did you join XXX, you know it's a ______.
>
> Don't mess this project up, or we'll be known as a _______ [company]!
>
> XXX takes pride in what it produces, we're not some ________ [company]!

The word/phrase can incorporate the meaning that it's a company or to be used as an adjective.

EDIT:

I want a very strong, powerful word, that would mean the place is really a hell-hole of firms. While *amateurish* or *incompetent* has a flavor of being bad - not all amateur companies are bad. I also don't mind common sayings like in Russian it could be something like "шарашкина контора" that has a meaning of a firm being untrustworthy, not serious, shady etc. Or similar.

I would also like to avoid words that doesn't mean that the company is bad but rather illegal or simply incompetent. I want to find a word or a common phrase that would mean a bad organisation. A synonym for "bad company" if you will.

Comment: **Bad company**, works best here. You don't need any other word for that. :)

Comment: @NVZ bad, terrible, horrible doesn't cut it. I need a word that would be less used but still known.

Comment: Fraudulent company?

Comment: How about *objectionable*? Or, *distasteful, unsavory*?

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan fraudulent has a different intension. I'm talking about either being a bad working environment or releasing a bad quality product. Fraudulence is different at least because it never intends to do whatever it promises in the first place.

Comment: @NVZ is there some stronger word that would describe a hellish work-environment? The words you've mentioned have a light feeling leaning more to "not everyone will agree with it, but some might".

Comment: @CreativeMagic You could use "hell" itself, metaphorically.

Comment: @CreativeMagic Horrendous company? or Horrible may be.

Comment: @CreativeMagic Is this question with regard to companies or you just want synonyms for *extremely bad*?

Comment: @NagarajanShanmuganathan I mean like a screaming boss, poor insurance, overwork, lack of direction, dysfunctional and (as a bonus) as a result - bad product. Although it might be hard to find a word or saying to describe all of those, only being extremely bad is enough for me.

Comment: @CreativeMagic I think you can consider my previous comment. Horrendous suits better.

Comment: There are simply too many words to consider.

Comment: "Unprofessional" if you want to be professional.  "Shitshow" if you don't.

Comment: *Dodgy* would fit, much like myriad other pejorative adjectives, this question is **too broad**.

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey - That's sexist!!

Comment: The problem is that a company may be "bad" for a hundred different reasons, and the appropriate descriptive term would depend very much on what makes it bad.

Comment: @HotLicks It's sexist?!

Comment: You're implying that only broads don't like their companies! ;)

Comment: This is still **too broad.** What exactly did such a company do to deserve this treatment?

Answer (score 3):

I've worked there; it's a *[hellhole](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hellhole)*; a real *[snake pit](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/snake-pit?q=snake%20pit)*.

Comment: OP already used it in his question. Anyway, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe "second-rate" would work here - as this could equally apply to the way the company is managed, the quality of the work, the work environment, or the company as a whole?

It is negative, though perhaps not negative enough for what you need?

> [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/second%E2%80%93rate)'s definition is
>
> not very good : of ordinary or inferior quality

Comment: Or for emphasis, *third-rate* (or *fourth-rate*; an extreme form would be *nth rate*, at least for the mathematically inclined)

Answer (score 1):

***fly–by–night***

From [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fly%E2%80%93by%E2%80%93night):

> **fly–by–night**
>   *noun*
>
> Definition of fly–by–night
>
> 2 :  one **without established reputation or standing**; especially :  a
>   **shaky business enterprise**

Your examples:

> Why did you join XXX, you know it's a **fly-by-night**.
>
> Don't mess this project up, or we'll be known as a **fly-by-night**
>   [company]!
>
> XXX takes pride in what it produces, we're not some **fly-by-night**
>   [company]!

Answer (score 1):

Would "sweatshop" work in your context?

I believe it to be fairly ubiquitously used to negatively describe a firm with poor working conditions.

Just in case:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweatshop

Answer (score 1):

“Hostile Work Environment” is the phrase usually used in professional settings. It has a [legal meaning](http://corporate.findlaw.com/human-resources/how-much-is-enough-difficulties-defining-hostile-work.html) and a [colloquial one](https://www.hg.org/article.asp?id=37908), both of which capture the wrongness of a bad company.

Comment: Hello, 282. I think this is probably the best, most idiomatic answer (even though OP may not agree).  Add a reference or two (including an example from a dictionary if you can find one) and you should be upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I'd prefer to use "bad company" itself.

It meets all your requirements: single word or two words, bad working environment or produces bad results, non-archaic, does not belong to a very concrete type of company, and understandable by today's native English speaker.

**Bad company** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bad+company)

> Unsavory people (for one to spend time with).
>
> *"You are keeping some bad company these days, Bill, and if you get arrested, I am not bailing you out!"*
> *"My mom thinks my new friends are bad company, but I'm having so much fun with them!"*

Comment: The definitions are inappropriate. Also, OP gives 'bad company'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Inappropriate how? Also, I'm aware that OP gave 'bad company', which is why I explained why I'd still use that.

Comment: OP is asking for the commercial usage. / SWR's, if acceptable at all, can't be answered without a novel suggestion.

Comment: @NVZ thank you for your input, but I'm actually looking for synonym or at least a different way to write it. "Bad company" doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

For the sentences given I'd be inclined to use [incompetent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incompetent)/[amateurish](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/amateurish).

Comment: You must add some dictionary definitions to explain why you'd be inclined to use these words.

Comment: I'm sorry, you are absolutely right :) I will do so when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Consider **unethical**

Definition:  not conforming to approved standards of social or professional behavior; contrary to conscience, morality or law.

Example: *Corporate responsibility is not always realized. When companies become larger and extend to a global audience, they are often faced with some very unethical business practices*.

EDIT:  According to OP's response to comments, the term **crappy company** is a better fit.

> What I’ve found over the past 20 years of interviewing is that while I
>   love talking to people that worked at really great companies, I hire
>   more people that have worked at really bad companies.  You see, while
>   you learn some really good stuff working for great companies, I think
>   people actually learn more working for really crappy companies! ([source](http://timsackett.com/2015/04/02/the-true-value-of-working-for-a-crappy-company/))

Answer (score 0):

Does the word lowbred works here??

Lowbred

Meaning: lacking refinement or grace

Another suggestion is 'below par'
Meaning not upto the standards

Comment: I'd say that *lowbred* sounds slightly archaic and rings back to a discriminatory class-based system. While it may be an appropriate word based on its definition, I would hesitate before using it in speech. Also, try adding links to sources backing your point (try to prove me wrong!) as that improves your answer, making it more likely to be up-voted